# Why are my new files not getting the group writeable permission?

Tags: permissions, freebsd, acl

I would like to set up a directory such that all new files are group writeable, regardless of the umask setting of the individual user.

I've created a `stor` group and added all users to it. Then, I created the folder:

```
$ mkdir uaroot
$ chgrp stor uaroot
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 ua  stor  512 Dec 27 14:35 uaroot
```

I set the ACLs for it:

```
$ setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rx,mask::rwx uaroot
$ setfacl -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rx,mask::rwx uaroot
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 ua  stor  512 Dec 27 14:35 uaroot
```

I can see the ACLs set as:

```
$ getfacl uaroot
# file: uaroot
# owner: ua
# group: stor
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x

$ getfacl -d uaroot
# file: uaroot
# owner: ua
# group: stor
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

I thought this will have files inside this directory automatically get group writeable permission, but this wasn't the case:

```
$ cd uaroot
$ touch a
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ua  stor  0 Dec 27 14:38 a

$ getfacl a
# file: a
# owner: ua
# group: stor
user::rw-
group::rwx      # effective: r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

What does the `effective` callout mean above? What am I missing in order to have all files get group writeable permission?

Comment: I don't see the `default` keyword from your getfacl results!

Comment: I think you removed the default settings when you ran `setfacl -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rx,mask::rwx uaroot`! Rerun with that `-d` option.

Answer (score 2):

You cancelled your earlier setting when you ran `setfacl -m ::rwx,g::rwx,o::rx,mask::rwx uaroot`, without the `-`d option and with the `-m` which `modifies` the current ACL settings on an object, rerun it with the `-d` to get what you want.

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rx,mask::rwx uaroot
```

My test returns:

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 georgek georgek 0 Dec 28 08:04 koko/a
```

And note that the `default` keyword is missing as a result of you running that second `setfacl` command. You need to see

```
# file: koko/
# owner: georgek
# group: georgek
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

To be sure the defaults will apply to newly created files in that folder. And the `getfacl` for the created file for my test is

```
# file: koko/a
# owner: georgek
# group: georgek
user::rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Comment: Hi George, this is not it. The default ACLs do not get overridden because they are separate and independent of the normal ACLs. I believe you are assuming I'm using Linux when I'm actually using FreeBSD.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't stated...

Comment: Thanks for offering. I’ve investigated the issue further and have a more clear question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491272/how-to-explain-this-difference-in-linux-and-freebsd-acl-behaviour